# Recovering a matrix from its higher order polynomials

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be a stable matrix, i.e. $\rho(A)<1$, where $\rho(\cdot)$ is the spectral radius. For $t=0,1,\ldots,T,\ldots,$ we define
$$
\Gamma_t \triangleq \sum_{s=0}^{t} A^s (A^s)^\top.
$$

I am wondering if it's possible to uniquely recover $A$ (up to some permutation and sign flips of columns) if we have access to all the matrices $\Gamma_0, \Gamma_1,\ldots,\Gamma_T,\ldots$.

For simplicity I chose $A$ to be a symmetric matrix, i.e. $A=A^\top$. In this case, we can see that its possible to only recover $A^2$ uniquely and recovering $A$ seems hard as there can be many possible solutions.

So my question is if people studied Gramians in the context of recovering the matrices in the literature or Gramians alone do not suffice as we saw in the case of symmetric matrices above.

Comment: Which is then the question? The answer to it is already included, in general we cannot get $A$ from the many $(\Gamma_t)_t$!

Comment: @dan_fulea: I am wondering if it's possible to infer $A$ from using these Gramians and any other clever trick. At the moment, I am not aware of any and also if people studied this question in literature.

Comment: Is it ok to find just one solution if there could exist many or do you need to find all of them?

Comment: @mathreadler: Ideally I would want to know how all the possible set of solutions look like though one may not need all of them. In the case of $A$ being symmetric, we can see that all possible matrices whose squares are same as $A^2$ are candidate solutions.

Comment: Ok I dont have many ideas of how to go about finding or representing all solutions. For finding one solution, the transpose may complicate it. If transpose was not there I would propose trying some Newton-Rhapson method.